# get value from Current User´s Id to display in feed with flutter and firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter so bear with me please, I am trying to display cards fill with information that users create. I store that info in firestore and I would like to retrieve it.

My firebase cloud store is organized like this:
posts/currentUserId/usersPost/INFO

but i dont know how to add value in the currentUsersId when interacting with the cloud. so it says currentUserId next to document but I can´t find how to add value.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:expandable_card/expandable_card.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'post_details.dart';

class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'feed_screen';

  final String userId;
  FeedScreen({this.userId});

  @override
  _FeedScreenState createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {

  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot;
  CollectionReference collectionReference =

 Firestore.instance.collection('posts').document(**CurrentUserId**).collection('usersPosts');

  passData(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostDetails(
              snapshot: snap,
            )));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        snapshot = datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

to get currentuser Id in firebase you need [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and then you can get the value of currentuserId as follows

```
  final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        final CurrentUserId = user.uid;
//then
Firestore.instance.collection('posts').document(CurrentUserId).collection('usersPosts');
```